# Get sum of key values and get max date from a dictionary using a common id

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have an array of dict like this -

```
[{'id':'450', 'marks':'30', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'450', 'marks':'60', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'450', 'marks':'80', 'end_date':None},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'51', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'27', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

I want to get sum of marks and max date for common ids. For above data my output should look like -

```
[{'id':'450', 'marks':'170', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'78', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

I tried using `counter` but it is giving me sum of ids also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the keys together and then do the necessary operation(`max` and `sum`).

```
ll.sort(key=lambda x: x["id"])
result = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(ll, key=lambda x: x["id"]):
    group = list(group)
    result.append(
        {
            "id": key,
            "marks": sum(int(g["marks"]) for g in group),
            "end_date": max(g["end_date"] for g in group if g["end_date"]),
        }
    )


print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
[{'id': '450', 'marks': 170, 'end_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0)}, {'id': '452', 'marks': 78, 'end_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 0, 0)}]
```